# Use exported certificate with private key to logon using Kerberos

Tags: kerberos

First I just would like to mention, that my knowledge in windows authentification methods are very limited. So my question:

Is it possible to use custom credential provider in windows to log on, that accepts certificate, which I export from certificate store with private key.

As far as I know, Kerberos accepts username/password format and although certificate from smart card.

So my question is, how can I feed my exported certificate into Kerberos?

Answer (score 2):

**Note: The below holds assuming Microsoft did things properly and following. But Microsoft being Microsoft they didn't. [Smart-Card (certificate-based) logon is *only* supported when using Kerberos thanks to the custom Microsoft extension to Kerberos.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/windows-authentication/windows-logon-scenarios#BKMK_SmartCardLogon)**

> So my question is, how can I feed my exported certificate into Kerberos?

**Short Answer: You can't.

Long Answer: Technically, you can.**

To understand this, we need to take two detours: Namely the answer to your first question and to Kerberos. Let's do Kerberos first.

So, [Kerberos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol)) is a (complex) protocol that allows a client to authenticate with a (sequence of) central server(s) such that at the end the client's actual intended communication partner can be sure of the client's identity and has a shared key with them. All of this while only the client has to establish connections with the central server(s) and while the only pre-shared keys are between each party and the central server(s). Now, Kerberos relies entirely on symmetric cryptography, so from a protocol point of view authentication via asymmetric cryptography isn't (directly) an option. **I'm rather confident that Windows also doesn't support this natively (short answer).**

*However*, the answer to your question

> Is it possible to use custom credential provider in windows to log on, that accepts certificate, which I export from certificate store with private key.

is yes. There is software that allows you to log-in to local Windows installations using a smart card and it's a built-in ability if the authentication is handled by a domain controller. Note though that using an encrypted exported private key isn't a sensible authentication method on its own, as you would be back to username (identifiying the relevant keyfile) and password (decrypting it) and would have gained nothing.

If you have a smart card and use this smart card to decrypt a windows password, then you can use this decrypted password for Kerberos authentication. Doing the first part is possible, as demonstrated by the software which feeds the password to the standard Windows login facilities after decryption for local logon. Doing the latter shouldn't be too hard. Please note that implementing this is likely *a lot* of effort and only potentially worth it in an environment where you cannot possibly switch away from using Kerberos to use "normal" domain-controller-based public-key authentication. This is why the longer answer is "you can".

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and detailed answer.
According to my understanding I have simple RFID card, which stores only ID, so it is not a smart card, with its own private key, so I can not use any of the Kerberos built in functionality which is based on login with smart card, which stores private certificate and PIN code. So I think I understand a bit more now, why I can not do it in normal way with Kerberos.

If I understand correctly you refer to Digest authentication? It is alternative to Kerberos, and I can feed my custom certificate? Or I am understanding this completely wrong

Comment: @Theodor MS Digest authentication seems to be symmetric-only, so doesn't support private keys and certificates. However I just checked _how_ Windows supports smart cards and it turns out Windows _does_ support Smart-Cards _only_ when Kerberos is used. That's a custom protocol extension by them.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I do not have smart card, I have only RFID card with tag inside. I wanted just based on RFID tag take a certificate(exported from windows, or certificate store) with private key and feed it in Kerberos. But I have kinda abandoned that idea as colleague pointed out, that my solution will be as safe as rfid tag. And that RFID tag can be copied with almost anything, so no matter what we do, solution will be unsafe